# Model.fit() output in Tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use TF 2.0 for MNIST dataset with batch size of 128.

During learning I get the following message in an EPOCH. If my batch size is 128, what does 375 signify?

Epoch 13/200
375/375 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2351 - accuracy: 0.9330 - val_loss: 0.2258 - val_accuracy: 0.9370

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
# Network and training parameters.
EPOCHS = 200
BATCH_SIZE = 128
VERBOSE = 1
NB_CLASSES = 10   # number of outputs = number of digits
N_HIDDEN = 128
VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.2 # how much TRAIN is reserved for VALIDATION
# Loading MNIST dataset.
# verify
# You can verify that the split between train and test is 60,000, and 10,000 respectively. 
# Labels have one-hot representation.is automatically applied
mnist = keras.datasets.mnist
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()
# X_train is 60000 rows of 28x28 values; we  --> reshape it to 
# 60000 x 784.
RESHAPED = 784
#
X_train = X_train.reshape(60000, RESHAPED)
X_test = X_test.reshape(10000, RESHAPED)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
# Normalize inputs to be within in [0, 1].
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')
# One-hot representation of the labels.
Y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_train, NB_CLASSES)
Y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_test, NB_CLASSES)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(N_HIDDEN,
          input_shape=(RESHAPED,),
          name='dense_layer', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(N_HIDDEN,
          name='dense_layer_2', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(NB_CLASSES,
          name='dense_layer_3', activation='softmax'))

# Compiling the model.
model.compile(optimizer='SGD', 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


# Training the model.
model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
               batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS,
               verbose=VERBOSE, validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 375 is the **number of steps per epoch** your model must complete in order to finish one epoch.  (Every epoch your model will process *steps_per_epoch* number of batches)

```
steps_per_epoch = len(X_train) // batch_size
```

but for your case, since you have specified 0.20 value to the validation_split parameter to model.fit()

```
steps_per_epoch = (len(X_train)*(1-VALIDATION_SPLIT)) // batch_size
```

so plugging the values,

> steps = ((60,000) * (1-0.20)) // 128  = 375

Comment: Good answer, any source for steps_per_epoch?